# Android Spinner item White space

Tags: android-spinner

When I clicked spinner, there is white area above of first item. I can't resolve this. I tried a lot of solution.

[image]

Activity class :

```
        ArrayAdapter<AramaTuru> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<AramaTuru>(IsyeriAramaActivity.this,R.layout.simple_list_item_arama, listAramaTurleri);
    spnAramaSecenekler.setAdapter(adapter);
```

simple_list_item_arama :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/kirmizi"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:padding="5dip"
android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
android:textSize="18dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

try to remove the padding. it gives spacing on all sides.